# what is a good way to pretty print a SQLAlchemy database as models and relations?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

This one might be a challenge, but I am trying to find a nice way to get an overarching idea of how my entire database "looks". Here is a small example using `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, a few models with different relations and properties (admittedly, most just taken from SQLAlchemy Docs)

```
class IDModel(db.Model):
  __abstract__ = True
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model, IDModel):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
  _roles = db.relationship(
    Role, lambda: user_role, collection_class=set,
    backref=db.backref('users', collection_class=set)
  )
  roles = association_proxy('_roles', 'name')

# One-to-many
class Post(db.Model, IDModel):
  __tablename__ = 'posts'
  html = db.Column(db.Text)
  author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, backref="users.id")
  author = db.relationship("User")

# Many-to-Many
class Role(db.Model, IDModel):
  __tablename__ = 'roles'
  name = db.Column(db.String)

user_role = db.Table(
  'user_role',
  db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True),
  db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Role.id), primary_key=True)
)
```

Ideally, what I want to do is change the `__repr__` of my db to print something like the following for a given db:

```
<Model 'User'>
id (primary key)
username
roles -> MANY-TO-MANY relationship with <Model 'Roles'>

<Model 'Post'>
id (primary_key)
html
author_id -> 'User.id'
author -> ONE-TO-MANY relationship with <Model 'User'>

<Model 'Role'>
id (primary key)
name
MANY TO MANY relationship with <Model 'User'>
```

is such a thing possible?

to add my contribution, I was able to make it print ALL the tables and their columns, but am having trouble pretty printing the relationships and removing the relationship tables.

```
>>> from app import db
>>> inspector = db.inspect(db.engine)
>>> for table in inspector.get_table_names():
        print("<Model '{}'".format(table))
        for column in inspector.get_columns(table):
            print(column['name'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to reflect the database to do this; you can inspect each of your models instead. To get a list of all models inheriting from `Base`:

```
Base.__subclasses__()
```

Then, to get a list of columns for a particular model, e.g. `User`, you can look at the mapper:

```
User.__mapper__.attrs
```

Each of those can be a `ColumnProperty` or `RelationshipProperty`. For a `ColumnProperty`, you can get the `Column` object (it's actually a list of `Column`s, but I think it's rare to have more than one):

```
prop.columns[0]
```

The `Column` object has all the information you've defined when you declared the model, including whether it's a primary key (`c.primary_key`) or a foreign key (`c.foreign_keys`).

For a `RelationshipProperty`, you can get the mapper of the remote side with `c.mapper`. To get the class, you can do `c.mapper.class_`. You can also find the direction with `c.direction`.

Putting it all together:

```
for model in Base.__subclasses__():
    print "<model {}>".format(model.__name__)
    for a in model.__mapper__.attrs:
        if isinstance(a, ColumnProperty):
            c = a.columns[0]
            line = a.key
            if c.primary_key:
                line += " (primary key)"
            if c.foreign_keys:
                line += " -> " + ", ".join([fk.target_fullname for fk in c.foreign_keys])
            print line
        elif isinstance(a, RelationshipProperty):
            print "{} -> {} relationship with <model {}>".format(
                a.key, a.direction.name, a.mapper.class_.__name__)
    print ""
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, 2 solutions exist:

1. https://github.com/manicmaniac/sqlalchemy-repr - cool, but prints ALL attributes which can lead to huge `repr`'s.
2. [https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#beauty-**repr**](https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#beauty-__repr__) - inspired by first one; allows you to specify attributes you want to see in `repr`.